# Change Field Type

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm using the following code to associate Contact to Account based on Domain field (type=text).

```
trigger AssociateContact on Contact (before insert) 
{
    List<String> contactEmaildomains = new List<String>();
    for(Contact contact:Trigger.new)

   {  if(contact.Autocreated__c && string.isNotBlank(contact.Domain__c))
        contactEmaildomains.add('%'+contact.Domain__c+'%');
    }
    System.debug(contactEmaildomains);
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT 
            Id, Domain__c 
         FROM 
            Account
         WHERE 
            Domain__c LIKE :contactEmaildomains];
    System.debug(accounts);

    Map<String, Id> domains = new Map<String, Id>();

    for(Account record: accounts) 
    {
        for(String dom:record.Domain__c.Split(','))
            domains.put(dom, record.Id);
    }
    for(Contact record: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if(domains.get(record.Domain__c) != null ) 
        {
            record.AccountId = domains.get(record.Domain__c);
        } else if (string.isNotBlank(record.email) && record.Autocreated__c == true) { record.AccountId = '0016100000J1K3c';}

    }
}
```

I'd like to change the field type to Long Text Area. In order to do that, I need to update the trigger to avoid this error:

> field 'Domain__c' can not be filtered in query call

I hope that someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you couldn't comment out the code,
You can trade it as string. so that sfdc would not detect the field. 
need to change: contact.Domain__c 
to: (string) contact.get('Domain__c')

Also change the query to dynamic query: 
`List<Account> accounts = Database.query('SELECT Id, Domain__c FROM Account ' + ' WHERE Domain__c LIKE '+ :contactEmaildomains);`
Since Long Text Area can not be filtered. you should change query using sub query.

```
List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
for(Contact contact:Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(contact.AccountId);
}
List<Account> accountList = Database.Query(
'SELECT Id, Domain__c,' +
       '(SELECT Id FROM Contacts WHERE Autocreated__c = true) ' +
'FROM Account WHERE Id IN '+ :accountIds);
```

Then you can loop accountList for further use.

Comment: Thank you. I update the trigger and now I'm encountering with the following error: Apex trigger AssociateContact caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: AssociateContact: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.QueryException: field 'Domain__c' can not be filtered in query call: ()

Comment: Long Text Area can not be filtered.
you should change query using sub query.